# Regex to replace text between two strings c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string :

```
 <span><style>
.G9cT{display:none}
.Q-Bv{display:inline}
</style><span class="G9cT">74</span><span style="display:none">100</span><span class="G9cT">100</span><div style="display:none">100</div><span style="display:none">122</span><span class="G9cT">122</span><div style="display:none">122</div><span style="display:none">178</span><span class="G9cT">178</span><span class="165">189</span><span class="G9cT">202</span><div style="display:none">202</div><span style="display:none">214</span><span class="G9cT">214</span><div style="display:none">214</div><span style="display:none">230</span><div style="display:none">230</div><span class="Q-Bv">.</span><span style="display:none">53</span><span class="G9cT">53</span><span class="G9cT">68</span><div style="display:none">68</div><span style="display:none">81</span><span class="G9cT">81</span><div style="display:none">81</div><span style="display: inline">112</span><span style="display:none">124</span><span class="G9cT">124</span><div style="display:none">127</div><span style="display:none">129</span><span class="G9cT">129</span><span></span><span class="G9cT">151</span><div style="display:none">155</div><span style="display:none">194</span><div style="display:none">194</div><span style="display:none">233</span><span class="G9cT">233</span><span></span><span class="G9cT">234</span><span class="Q-Bv">.</span><span></span><div style="display:none">61</div>88<div style="display:none">98</div><span style="display:none">105</span><span class="G9cT">105</span><div style="display:none">105</div><div style="display:none">117</div><span style="display:none">197</span><span class="G9cT">197</span><div style="display:none">197</div><span style="display: inline">.</span><span class="Q-Bv">65</span><span style="display:none">147</span><div style="display:none">147</div></span>
```

And i am using `Regex` to replace  the above string with Empty in between two tags `<span style="display:none"> * </span>` . I am using the code below:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<span style=\"display:none\">(.*)</span>");
var v = regex.Match(txxt);
string output = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(txxt, "<span style=\"display:none\">(.*)</span>", "");
```

But the above replaces the string from first `<span style=\"display:none\">` till end.I have tried different combinations. Any advise.

Comment: yup, check this out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `.*?` instead , its lazy , your `.*` is greedy.

the greedy regex eats up everything after the match it gets. while .*? is reluctant to match and will only match till where the condition is satisfied

Comment: Perfect thank you sir, and what if i only want to replace the tags but not the content inside?

Comment: @confusedMind depends on which tag you want to replace. you always have an option of lookahead or lookbehind

Comment: @aelor repalce tha tags found using the expression above but not the content inside.

Comment: @confusedMind you mean to say that you wan to replace the `span style="display:none"` with something wlse

Comment: @aelor  example : replace <span style="display:none">123</span> to only 123 . But i cannot use simple replace function need to use regex as above.

Comment: replace `<span style="display:none">(.*?)</span>` with `\1` or `$1` whichever backreference your lang suppots

Comment: @aelor nope it actually replaces the string to \1 or $1 .

Comment: i ll show you an example here : http://regex101.com/r/aV8cZ2 see the resulting text

Comment: @confusedMind for c# i think you use it like this : `Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "$1")`